# Phonegap can't pause <video> when backing out of view (on Android)

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, video

I've inherited a Phonegap app on Android, also using jquery mobile, from a couple of years ago and I've got a problem with trying to stop videos playing when backing out of pages.

The videos I'm playing are hosted externally, so the HTML is really simple like:

```
<p>
  <video width="100%" controls><source src="http://website.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
</p>
```

I've been trying to just call the `pause()` method on the `video`'s DOM element when the page is getting hidden. I've got this code listening for the `pagebeforehide` event. This code is definitely getting called, but doesn't work:

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforehide", function( e, data ) {
    var videos = $('.ui-page-active').find('video');
    if(videos.length > 0)
    {
        videos.each(function() {
            alert('about to stop video : ' + $(this).html());
            this.pause();
            alert('should be stopped.');
        });
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

Weirdly, if I add a link directly in the HTML to pause the video, it works. Once I've paused the video with javascript in the page, the code to pause the video as the page hides starts working!?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

 function playPause() 
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig()
{ 
 myVideo.width = 560; 
} 

function makeSmall() 
{ 
 myVideo.width = 320; 
} 


 function makeNormal() 
{ 
  myVideo.width = 420; 
} 




<video id="video1" width="420">
<source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I agree that this code would work just fine in a desktop browser. In fact, this code would work in an embedded Android webview provided the functions were triggered from an `onClick` event. However it doesn't work if you try to call these methods as part of the jquery mobile page events.

Comment: see this link i use this in my phonegap project. it's working  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: I'm sure it works in iOS; in fact you probably don't even need to bother with this javascript in iOS, because the iOS UIWebView is smart enough to stop an embedded video playing when the view is unloaded. This is very much an Android-specific problem. However, I appreciate your help.